# how to rotate a UIView to face a point

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, rotation

I have a UIView that I want to rotate when I move my finger across the screen (like in a circle). I want the UIView to rotate so that it faces my touchpoint. I then want to shoot something from my UIView (like a bullet) in the direction that the UIView is facing. Any Ideas???

Answer (score 2):

Glad I remember triginometry

```
-(void)degreesToRotateObjectWithPosition:(CGPoint)objPos andTouchPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint{

   float dX = touchPoint.x-objPos.x;        // distance along X
   float dY = touchPoint.y-objPos.y;        // distance along Y
   float radians = atan2(dY, dX);          // tan = opp / adj

   //Now we have to convert radians to degrees:
   float degrees = radians*M_PI/360;

   return degrees;
}
```

Once you have your nice method, just do this:

```
CGAffineTransform current = view.transform;

[view setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(current,
                 [view degreesTorotateObjectWithPosition:view.frame.origin 
                                  andTouchPoint:[touch locationInView:parentView]]

//Note: parentView = The view that your object to rotate is sitting in.
```

This is pretty much all the code that you'll need.The math is right, but I'm not sure about the setTransform stuff. I'm at school writing this in a browser. You should be able to figure it out from here.

Good luck,

Aurum Aquila